# Adding Sum per row in PIVOT using LINQ

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have following function that converts normal DataTable to Pivot Table.

But I have 1 more requirement, it should also show Value column i.e sum of all the Pivot column cell.

```
e.g. : ORDER | SUM | PLANDATE
         1      50    10-Oct-2012
         1      10    10-Oct-2012
         2      15    12-Oct-2012
```

After PIVOT it should be like

```
ORDER | SUM | 10-Oct-2012 | 12-Oct-2012
  1      60     50            10
  2      15                   15
```

my pivot function is :

```
DataTable Pivot(DataTable dt, DataColumn pivotColumn, DataColumn pivotValue) {
    // find primary key columns 
    //(i.e. everything but pivot column and pivot value)
    DataTable temp = dt.Copy();
    temp.Columns.Remove( pivotColumn.ColumnName );
    temp.Columns.Remove( pivotValue.ColumnName );
    string[] pkColumnNames = temp.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
        .Select( c => c.ColumnName )
        .ToArray();

    // prep results table
    DataTable result = temp.DefaultView.ToTable(true, pkColumnNames).Copy();
    result.PrimaryKey = result.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToArray();
    dt.AsEnumerable()
        .Select(r => r[pivotColumn.ColumnName].ToString())
        .Distinct().ToList()
        .ForEach (c => result.Columns.Add(c, pivotColumn.DataType));

    // load it
    foreach( DataRow row in dt.Rows ) {
        // find row to update
        DataRow aggRow = result.Rows.Find(
            pkColumnNames
                .Select( c => row[c] )
                .ToArray() );
        // the aggregate used here is LATEST 
        // adjust the next line if you want (SUM, MAX, etc...)
        aggRow[row[pivotColumn.ColumnName].ToString()] = row[pivotValue.ColumnName];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Thanks & any help will be appriciated...

```
Sample Data :
 OrderStatus    Qty     Dated
    New 100 10-Oct-2012
    New 150 10-Oct-2012
    New 100 10-Oct-2012
    Conf    200 12-Oct-2012
    New 100 12-Oct-2012
    Reconf  300 12-Oct-2012
    New 200 15-Oct-2012
    New 200 15-Oct-2012
    Reconf  100 18-Oct-2012
    New 150 18-Oct-2012
    Conf    150 18-Oct-2012
    New 100 20-Oct-2012
    Reconf  500 20-Oct-2012
    New 100 30-Oct-2012
    New 700 30-Oct-2012
    New 100 30-Oct-2012
    Conf    100 10-Oct-2012
```

**Update Code** :

```
 private DataTable DataTableToPivot(DataTable dtNormalTable, DataColumn pivotColumn, DataColumn valueColumn)
            {
                cTracing.WriteTrace("Inside DataTableToPivot", "DataTableToPivot");

                DataTable dtPivot = null;
                DataTable tempPivot = null;
                DataColumn sumColumn = new DataColumn();
                string[] pkColumnNames = null;

                try
                {
                    sumColumn.ColumnName = valueColumn.ColumnName;
                    sumColumn.DataType = typeof(string);
                    sumColumn.DefaultValue = "0";

var allrows = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(delegate(DataRow r)
            {
                DataRow nr = dt.NewRow();
                foreach (DataColumn item in dt.Columns)
                {
                    nr.SetField(item.ColumnName, r[item.ColumnName] is DBNull ? string.Empty : r[item.ColumnName]);
                }
                return nr;
            });

            dtNormalTable = allrows.CopyToDataTable();

                    // find primary key columns 
                    //(i.e. everything but pivot column and pivot value)
                    tempPivot = dtNormalTable.Copy();

                    tempPivot.Columns.Remove(pivotColumn.ColumnName);
                    tempPivot.Columns.Remove(valueColumn.ColumnName);

                    pkColumnNames = tempPivot.Columns
                                                 .Cast<DataColumn>()
                                                 .Select(c => c.ColumnName)
                                                 .ToArray();

                    // prep results table
                    dtPivot = tempPivot.DefaultView.ToTable(true, pkColumnNames).Copy();
                    dtPivot.PrimaryKey = dtPivot.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToArray();
                    // include the sum column
                    dtPivot.Columns.Add(sumColumn);
                    try
                    {
                        dtNormalTable.AsEnumerable()
                          .Select(r => r[pivotColumn.ColumnName].ToString())
                          .Distinct()
                          .ToList()
                          .ForEach(c => dtPivot.Columns.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(c).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"), typeof(string)));
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        dtNormalTable.AsEnumerable()
                          .Select(r => r[pivotColumn.ColumnName].ToString())
                          .Distinct()
                          .ToList()
                          .ForEach(c => dtPivot.Columns.Add(c, typeof(string)));
                    }

                    // load it
                    foreach (DataRow row in dtNormalTable.Rows)
                    {
                        // find row to update
                        DataRow aggRow = dtPivot.Rows.Find(
                            pkColumnNames
                                         .Select(c => row[c])
                                         .ToArray());
                        // the aggregate used here is LATEST 
                        // adjust the next line if you want (SUM, MAX, etc...)
                        string columnName = string.Empty;
                        try
                        {
                            columnName = Convert.ToDateTime(row[pivotColumn.ColumnName]).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            columnName = row[pivotColumn.ColumnName].ToString();
                        }

                        if (aggRow.IsNull(columnName))
                        {
                            aggRow[columnName] = Convert.ToDecimal(row[valueColumn.ColumnName]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            aggRow[columnName] = Convert.ToDecimal(aggRow[columnName]) +
                                                 Convert.ToDecimal(row[valueColumn.ColumnName]);
                        }

                        if (numberFormat == "3")
                        {
                            // add the value to the sum
                            aggRow[sumColumn] = (Convert.ToDecimal(aggRow[sumColumn].ToString()) +
                                                Convert.ToDecimal(row[valueColumn.ColumnName].ToString())).ToString("#0.000");
                        }
                        else if (numberFormat == "2")
                        {
                            // add the value to the sum
                            aggRow[sumColumn] = (Convert.ToDecimal(aggRow[sumColumn].ToString()) +
                                                Convert.ToDecimal(row[valueColumn.ColumnName].ToString())).ToString("#0.00");
                        }
                        else if (numberFormat == "1")
                        {
                            // add the value to the sum
                            aggRow[sumColumn] = (Convert.ToDecimal(aggRow[sumColumn].ToString()) +
                                                Convert.ToDecimal(row[valueColumn.ColumnName].ToString())).ToString("#0.0");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // add the value to the sum
                            aggRow[sumColumn] = (Convert.ToDecimal(aggRow[sumColumn].ToString()) +
                                                Convert.ToDecimal(row[valueColumn.ColumnName].ToString())).ToString("#0");
                        }
                    }

                    return dtPivot;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    cTracing.WriteTrace("Error inside DataTableToPivot", "DataTableToPivot");
                    cLogging.WriteLog(ex);
                    return null;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (dtPivot != null)
                        dtPivot.Dispose();
                }
            }
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding each row's value to the sum column in the corresponding aggregate row?

```
DataTable Pivot(DataTable dt, DataColumn pivotColumn, DataColumn pivotValue) {
    DataColumn sumColumn = new DataColumn();
    sumColumn.ColumnName = "SUM";
    sumColumn.DataType = typeof(int);
    sumColumn.DefaultValue = 0;

    // find primary key columns 
    //(i.e. everything but pivot column and pivot value)
    DataTable temp = dt.Copy();
    temp.Columns.Remove( pivotColumn.ColumnName );
    temp.Columns.Remove( pivotValue.ColumnName );
    string[] pkColumnNames = temp.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
        .Select( c => c.ColumnName )
        .ToArray();

    // prep results table
    DataTable result = temp.DefaultView.ToTable(true, pkColumnNames).Copy();
    result.PrimaryKey = result.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToArray();
    // include the sum column
    result.Columns.Add(sumColumn);
    dt.AsEnumerable()
        .Select(r => r[pivotColumn.ColumnName].ToString())
        .Distinct()
        .OrderBy(c => Convert.ToDateTime(c))   // Order by the date
        .ToList()
        .ForEach (c => result.Columns.Add(c, pivotColumn.DataType));

    // load it
    foreach( DataRow row in dt.Rows ) {
        // find row to update
        DataRow aggRow = result.Rows.Find(
            pkColumnNames
                .Select( c => row[c] )
                .ToArray() );
        // the aggregate used here is LATEST 
        // adjust the next line if you want (SUM, MAX, etc...)
        string columnName = row[pivotColumn.ColumnName].ToString();
        if(aggRow.IsNull(columnName))
        {
            aggRow[columnName] = (int)row[pivotValue.ColumnName];          
        }
        else
        {
            aggRow[columnName] = Convert.ToInt32(aggRow[columnName]) +
                                 (int)row[pivotValue.ColumnName];
        }   
        // add the value to the sum
        aggRow[sumColumn] = (int)aggRow[sumColumn] + 
                            (int)row[pivotValue.ColumnName];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Its not working, giving error 
"Specified cast is not valid." on line : 
aggRow[sumColumnName] = (int)aggRow[sumColumnName] + (int)row[pivotValue.ColumnName];

Moreover value of aggRow[sumColumnName] is System.DBNull & its not a string its coming as object

Comment: @NikhilGupta: What is the type of SUM in your original table?

Comment: This is my table st.
            dtNormal.Columns.Add("OrderStatus");
            dtNormal.Columns.Add("Qty", typeof(int));
            dtNormal.Columns.Add("Dated");

            dtNormal.Rows.Add("New", 100, "10-Oct-2012");

Comment: @NikhilGupta: I fixed the issue of the sumColumn containing null values.

Comment: Martin, I found 1 issue with the original code. if u will try my sample date on this code u will see, it calculates the sum but it is not displaying all the columns e.g. if there is a Status "New" & for Date "10-Oct-2012" there are multiple Qty, which are not getting added up & resulting in wrong PIVOT, can u help on this :(

Comment: @NikhilGupta: How would you like to handle it?  The easiest way would be to have one column for the date and have the value be the sum of values on that date.  Otherwise we will have to find a way to work around duplicate column names, which might be possible, but will be trickier.

Comment: Hi Martin, thats what I want but if u will run the code with my  sample data u will see that sum column has some different value that the sum of the columns e.g. for Status "New" sum will b 2000 but if u will manually sum all the dates for "New" they will not b 2000. 

if there are two different entries for same date & status they should also b added & displayed as single value under that date but thats not happening....

Comment: @NikhilGupta Cool, I was just making sure that's what you wanted before I made any changes.  It should do what you want now.

Comment: Thanks Martin 4 ur help... U made my day :-)

Comment: Hey Martin, I have 1 small question. What if my SUM datatype is string in  base table???? What do I need to change :(

Comment: @NikhilGupta: Use `Convert.Int32()` or `int.Parse()` on `row[pivotValue.ColumnName]` instead of casting it to an `int`.

Comment: Hi Martin, I have updated my post with the final code I am using. I have 1 small requirement i.e. before converting Normal DataTable to Matrix it should be sorted by Date Field. I am unable to do that. Can u help me with that. Please have a look @ the final code. Thanks :)

Comment: @NikhilGupta: I updated my answer by adding `.OrderBy(c => Convert.ToDateTime(c))` when getting the dates from the original DataTable.  However, I'm not sure how this would be accomplished if `Convert.ToDateTime()` throws an exception.

Comment: Hi Martin, man need your help again.
One of my primary key column is null, so I am getting error on following line
`dtPivot.PrimaryKey = dtPivot.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToArray();`
Error : Column 'Old Price' has null values in it.
do you have any idea how to handle this???

Comment: @NikhilGupta: Good question!  You should definitely ask it separately.  I think other people may be able to help you better, and it could be helpful for folks with the same problem.

Comment: @NikhilGupta: Is `Old Price` supposed to be part of the primary key?  That is, would the result be different if it weren't?

Comment: @Martin: Need to check that but what if its not reqd. as primary key. How can we do it.
Is there a way??? & what if its required...

Comment: @NikhilGupta: If it's not required then the fix is simple: remove it from the list of primary key columns.  If it is required then one solution would be to convert the column's type to string and convert null values to empty strings.

Comment: @Martin : I solved the problem... Updated the code here also.
Things seem to be working fine on a sample, now will test it on the actual code... Thank u so much for all the help.
Lets hope this concludes everything reqd in a pivot :-)