# Getting DataTable column names using linq, error when column is null

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have a datatable with n columns & I am converting it to Pivot.

I already have a piece of code for converting it to Pivot, reference :

[Adding Sum per row in PIVOT using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995488/adding-sum-per-row-in-pivot-using-linq)

Now problem comes when there is a column with null values in it.

following line fails with error

```
dtPivot.PrimaryKey = dtPivot.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToArray();

Error : Column 'x' has null values in it.
```

Can any one help me, how to handle this...

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by looking at what exactly is causing the issue.

Add a breakpoint before the line, and see what items are contained in `dtPivot.Columns` (you can try to use `ToArray()`).

Are there items which are `null` or are there items with properties which are `null` that's causing the problem? You can check this by using the watch in the debugging window to try and cast an item from `dtPivot.Columns` manually to `DataColumn`, and see which ones throw errors (and possibly, WHY they throw errors).

If the error is because some of the items in `dtPivot.Columns` are `null`, then you could try and filter them out first using `Cast<object>().Where(o => o != null)`. If the error is because a property is `null`, then see if there isn't anything else you could cast the columns to first, and then try to filter the columns (or fill out the missing values, if need be).